# Basic questions about Faraday's law of induction

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm conducting an experiment related to electromagnetic induction, where I drop magnets into a solenoid. I'm trying to find out how the magnetic field strength of the magnet(s) affect the peak emf value. I have some questions about Faraday's law and my experiment. We know that

$$\epsilon = -N*\frac{\Delta BA}{\Delta t}$$

so, when dropping a magnet through a solenoid (perpendicularly),

1. is A constant here? Would it be the cross-sectional area (a circle)?
2. is $\Delta t$  the time taken for the magnet to pass through the solenoid? Or the time  taken for the magnet to pass through a specific cross-sectional area? If the latter, how do we measure that?
3. Would $\Delta t$ be constant?
4. If (1) and (3) are true , from the equation, $\epsilon = \frac{-NA}{\Delta t}*\Delta B$, so emf is directly proportional to $\Delta B$. Can I take this as: emf is directly proportional to $B$?

Sorry if my questions are basic, but I'm trying my best to understand what's happening. Any help would be really appreciated! Thank you, and let me know if anything about this post is wrong, I'm new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it's a little complicated, though simple in principle.

(a) As the magnet enters the solenoid its flux is linked with more and more turns, and, as it leaves, with fewer and fewer turns. Therefore multiplication by $N$, if $N$ is the total number of turns, is inappropriate.

(b) We need to go back to the equation
$$\mathscr E = -\frac {\Delta \Phi}{\Delta t}$$
in which $\Phi$ is the flux *linkage*. I'd like to say that $\Phi =nBA$ in which $n$ is the number of turns linked, A is the area of a turn and B is the flux density. Unfortunately $\Phi$ can't correctly be written as a simple product like this. The reason is that for any turn, the flux density will vary over its area, and different turns will have different amounts of flux linked with them. It's easy to see this by drawing a magnet entering a solenoid and then drawing in some of the magnet's field lines.

What's to be done? You could write something horrible like
$$\mathscr E = -\frac {\text d}{\text dt} \left(\sum_0^N \int_A\mathbf B\cdot \text d\mathbf A \right)$$
but making further progress would be difficult.

(c) What is the meaning of $\Delta t$? It is the time taken for the flux to change by $\Delta \Phi$. So you *could* choose the time the magnet takes to drop through the solenoid in which case $\Delta \Phi$ would be the corresponding change in flux linkage. $\frac{\Delta \Phi}{\Delta t}$ would then give you the *mean* emf in the solenoid as the magnet drops through it. At the other extreme we could make $\Delta t$ very small and put in the corresponding flux change $\Delta \Phi$. This would give us something approximating to the instantaneous emf.

(d) Where does all this leave you for your practical investigation? I'd say that the only easy relationship to investigate would be that between the peak emf induced and the speed at which the magnet is falling. [There will also be proportionality between the emf and the magnet's strength (as determined, for example, by the field strength at a given distance along its axis from its centre) but you'd have to source magnets of the same size and shape but different strengths – not easy!]

I'm sorry if this is not as straightforward as you'd hoped.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. It is really more complicated than I expected it to be - but  this helped a lot in terms of my understanding. If you don't mind me asking an extra question, what is the reason behind having to use the 'same' magnet with varying strengths? Is it because the shape affects how the flux density will vary over different turns?

Comment: "Is it because the shape affects how the flux density will vary over different turns?" Exactly so. But, as I hinted, I don't think that sourcing magnets of the same shape but different strength would be possible. But the experiment in which you drop magnets from different heights through the solenoid ($v \propto \sqrt h$) and record the maximum emf works well.

Comment: right. Just wanted to know why - your suggested experiment sounds way more reasonable. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @PhillipWood What do you mean by $v\propto\sqrt h$? Is this assuming the solenoid won't exert a force on the magnet?

Comment: @ BioPhysicist Yes, I am assuming that, because I'm assuming that a modern voltmeter or oscilloscope (impedance > 10 MΩ) is all that will be connected across the solenoid, so there'll be negligible current in the solenoid and negligible force between it and the magnet. [Incidentally, thanks for editing my answer. I can't see any changes – what exactly did you do?]